# How to get nodes to be placed in relation to edge anchors?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I would like the chart that is generated for these nodes to roughly reflect the direction information that I put on each of the nodes:

```
digraph some_continents {
    north_america:s      -> south_america:n     [label="S"];
    north_america:e      -> europe:w            [label="E"];
    europe:s             -> africa:n            [label="S"];
    south_america:e      -> africa:w            [label="E"];
    europe:e             -> asia:w              [label="E"];
}
```

What I get for `dot -Tpng in.dot > out.png` is

[image]

I would prefer that the nodes were positioned so that the  "eastward" arrows were just straight lines to the right, and that the "southward" arrows were just straight lines down.

Can this be achieved using one of the graphviz generators, with the right paramters?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are after, but

- changed to **splines=line**
- used **rank=same** to set ranking (see https://graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf)

```
digraph some_continents {
graph [splines=line]
{ rank=same  north_america europe asia  }
{rank=same south_america africa }
    north_america:s      -> south_america:n     [label="S"];
    north_america:e      -> europe:w            [label="E"];
    europe:s             -> africa:n            [label="S"];
    south_america:e      -> africa:w            [label="E"];
    europe:e             -> asia:w              [label="E"];
}
```

Giving:
[image]

[Late requirements (the way of the world). ]
The Graphviz language does not include ranking based on (ports, seemingly).  [The language has no conditionals]
However, you can write a pre-processor in **gvpr** (https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf) (or other Graphviz-aware languages) that would investigate the ports used for each edge and as needed:

- create a subgraph
- add **rank=same** attribute
- insert head & tail nodes for "east-west" edges into the new subgraph (note, subgraph, not cluster)

Doable, but a little fussy.  Sorry.

On reflection, since you are programmatically generating the input file, your program could be enhanced to do the pre-processing I describe above.  One new subgraph per east-west edge.  Easy-peasy (maybe).

Comment: Thanks @sroush, your final image is what I'm after, but I want the ranks to be inferred from the edge anchors; I don't want to have to figure the layout out myself and hard code the ranks. Follow me?